# Condense ArrayList based on property in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have Java ArrayList of Objects, which I want to condense into as few items in an Array as possible after comparing the unitPrice property

Take the following ArrayList as example

```
 data = [ 
  {itemName: "Apple", purchaseDate: "Jan 01 2017", purchasedQuantity: 10, unitPrice:10},
  {itemName: "Apple", purchaseDate: "Feb 01 2017", purchasedQuantity: 12, unitPrice:10},
  {itemName: "Apple", purchaseDate: "Mar 01 2017", purchasedQuantity: 14, unitPrice:15},
  {itemName: "Apple", purchaseDate: "Apr 01 2017", purchasedQuantity: 16, unitPrice:15},
  {itemName: "Apple", purchaseDate: "May 01 2017", purchasedQuantity: 18, unitPrice:10}
]
```

In the above example 0th, 1st and 4th Item have the same unitPrice and the remaining two have same. I would like it to condense the 0th, 1st and 4th Item into one item and 2nd and 3rd into another after adding the purchasedQuanity like so

```
 data = [ 
  {itemName: "Apple", purchaseDate: "Jan 01 2017", purchasedQuantity: 40, unitPrice:10},
  {itemName: "Apple", purchaseDate: "Mar 01 2017", purchasedQuantity: 30, unitPrice:15}
]
```

I tried the following code

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){
            int productQuantityInStock = 0;
                for(int k = 0; k < data.size()-1; k++){
                    if((i != k+1) && (data.get(i).getunitPrice().equals(data.get(k+1).getunitPrice()))){
                        productQuantityInStock = Integer.parseInt(data.get(i).getpurchasedQuantity()) + Integer.parseInt(data.get(k + 1).getpurchasedQuantity());
                        data.get(i).setProductInStock(String.valueOf(productQuantityInStock));
                        data.remove(k + 1);
                    }

            }
        }
```

But I am not getting desired result.

Comment: Iterate the list in reverse when you're doing the removal.

Comment: why not using enhanced for loop

Comment: What result are you getting and what result do you expect?

Comment: @Charlie As the loop goes on it reaches a certain point where it checks itself and deletes itself.

Comment: Please use a consistent numeration scheme: your 5th item actually is the 4th one if you start counting at 0.

Comment: @p.p. Edited the array index from 5th to 4th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of the problem in your code, this is a classic problem: you're removing elements from the list whilst iterating forwards.

This means that when you remove element `k+1`, the element formerly at index `k+2` becomes the new element at index `k+1`; you then increment `k`, so you never check that element again.

The easiest fix here is just to iterate `k` in reverse:

```
for(int k = data.size()-2; k >= 0; k--){
```

Note that you're always using `k+1`, rather than `k`, so you might find it easier just to use

```
for(int k = data.size()-1; k > 0; k--){
```

and replace `k+1` with `k` in the body.

---

This looks like a problem that might be better solved using streams.

Group your items by the price, and then use a downstream collector to aggregate them.

```
Collection<Item> reduced = data.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getunitPrice),
        Collectors.reducing((i, j) -> {
            int productQuantityInStock = Integer.parseInt(i.getpurchasedQuantity()) + Integer.parseInt(j).getpurchasedQuantity());
            i.setProductInStock(String.valueOf(productQuantityInStock));
            return i;
        })
    .values();
```

(Incidentally, storing the purchased quantity and quantity in stock as streams doesn't look like a very good idea. If you're parsing them as ints, and storing the string representation of ints, why not just use ints?)

Answer (score 1):

First, you won't be able to modify the data list while you iterate over it as it will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Second, what should the purchase date be when the items are merged?

Third, it may help to create a second data structure to store the results while you work through them. It will not be as computationally complex as you might expect. For example, a Map mapping from unit price to item data so you don't have to loop through more than once.

Fourth, you might try a two-pass approach:

1. Do what you're doing but instead of deleting the item from the list, just set the quantity to 0
2. Go through again adding each item with a quantity greater than zero to a new list
3. Change the reference to the old list to point to the new list